# 2D associative array in Python, or something similar

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm thinking of a way to store input parameters read from an XML configuration file. The file contains

- (database name, schema, table username and password) x3
- Year path to output file
- path to another file

In the XML file the values for the 3 databases are separated into different tags, for example there's `<marketing>...</marketing>` with all the info for connecting to the database inside. So I would like to be able to do

`inputParameters[marketing[username]]` or `inputParameters[marketing[password]]` etc. or something like that.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html

Comment: @rlbond I already use xml.etree.ElementTree but now am deciding what to store the result in

Answer (score 1):

It is called dictionary in Python and covered in documentation:

```
dbValues = {"password": "blabla", "path": "some/path", 0: "some number as key"}
```

Then you nest a dictionary inside a dictionary to achieve what you want.
When you want to add something it is:

```
dbValues["user"] = "root"

# Getting is as you wrote:
print "User:", dbValues["user"]
```

Dictionary can have any immutable object for a key, and anything for a value.

```
# Nested:
dbValues["paths"] = {"p1": "/usr/lib", "p2": "/etc"}
# Getting:
print "p1:", dbValues["paths"]["p1"]
```

Or to use them exactly as you described, use two separate dictionaries.